# Swapping Tab Order

Tags: vb.net, wpf

The code I have below swaps two tabs around.  This is done through creating an array, deleting all tabs and then recreating them which seems very inefficient to me.

```
Private Sub SwapTabs(ByVal tabOne As Tab, ByVal tabTwo As Tab)
    'get array of all tabs
    Dim tabs() As Tab = Me.Children.OfType(Of Tab).ToArray
    'swap the tabs in the array
    tabs(Me.Children.IndexOf(tabOne) - 1) = tabTwo
    tabs(Me.Children.IndexOf(tabTwo) - 1) = tabOne
    'remove all tabs from me
    Dim lengthOfChilds As Integer = (Me.Children.Count - 1)
    For index As Integer = lengthOfChilds To 0 Step -1
        Dim objAtIndex As Object = Me.Children.Item(index)
        If TypeOf objAtIndex Is Tab Then
            Me.Children.Remove(objAtIndex)
        End If
    Next
    'repopulate tabs
    For Each t As Tab In tabs
        Me.Children.Add(t)
    Next
End Sub
```

Is there a better or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What exactly does `Me` refer to here? It might be relevant.

Comment: @RubberDuck It references an overflowing dock panel (inherits dockpanel) I use to contain the tabs.

Comment: If there's a Insert function, just get the position of the two tabs, remove them, and Insert them starting from the smallest index.

Comment: Exactly why do you need to *swap tabs*? Is this code part of some "rearrange tab order" functionality? How is it called? Is the user dragging/dropping tabs? We need a bit more context here, otherwise this looks like a XY problem. Also WPF questions are typically better posts when they include the relevant XAML.

Comment: [Possibly relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10738247/1188513)